# Hive inner joins wrong result

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Two tables table1 and table 2

```
hive> select * from  table1 where  dt=20171020;
OK
a   1   1   p   10  20171020
b   2   2   q   10  20171020
c   3   3   r   10  20171020
d   4   4   r   10  20171020

hive> select * from  table2 where  dt=20171020;
OK
a   1   1   p   10  20171020
b   2   2   t   10  20171020
c   3   3   r   10  20171020

hive> select * from table1 t1
    > join table2 t2
    > on t1.c1=t2.c1
    > where
    > t1.dt=20171020 and t2.dt=20171020 and  
    > t1.c2 <> t2.c2 or t1.c3 <> t2.c3 or t1.c4 <> t2.c4  or t1.c5 <> t2.c5;

Result:
a   1   1   p   20  20171016    a   1   1   p   10  20171015
a   1   1   p   20  20171016    a   1   1   p   10  20171020
b   2   2   q   20  20171016    b   2   2   t   10  20171015
b   2   2   q   20  20171016    b   2   2   t   10  20171020
c   3   3   r   20  20171016    c   3   3   r   10  20171015
c   3   3   r   20  20171016    c   3   3   r   10  20171020
b   2   2   q   10  20171020    b   2   2   t   10  20171015
b   2   2   q   10  20171020    b   2   2   t   10  20171020
a   19  19  p   20  20171019    a   1   1   p   10  20171015
a   19  19  p   20  20171019    a   1   1   p   10  20171020
```

I want following row because this row got changed,how `hive` joins in the above code?

```
 b  2   2   q   10  20171020
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.Your join should be on date as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
            AND t1.dt = t2.dt
WHERE  t1.dt = 20171020
       AND ( t1.c2 <> t2.c2
              OR t1.c3 <> t2.c3
              OR t1.c4 <> t2.c4
              OR t1.c5 <> t2.c5 );
```

Comment: in practical, we have to use different dates liket1.dt=20171019 and t2.dt=20171020 . what is the use of adding dt in on condition?

Comment: if you do not add dt in join it will  apply OR condition for all dates.Also check the parentheses for OR. For various dates , you can exclude date but have OR in parrntheses